# Store multiple size of image or resize current image on a webserver

Tags: php, html, css, image

I want to know which is the best way to store and show images on a webserver. At the moment I have written a script in PHP that uses GD library to resize any image I want to, then it outputs the image.

For example my original image has 3000px x 4000px, and I want to display that image as a thumbnail. I simply put `<img src="image.php?n=image&w=300&h=400" alt="test" />`. If I click on that image I want to see the original size, so I will call the script again but without &h and &w parameters.

**My question is**:
Is it better to generate 3 images when I upload an image on my server (thumbnail size, medium size e.g. 800px x 600px, and original size) or to have a single image and resize it for each appearance via my PHP script ?

My server has 4GB RAM and 60GB storage capacity and and I expect at least 1k visitors everyday. Please take into account server performance too when answering.

P.S. I need a detailed answer and I already searched stackoverflow for similar information. I haven't found nothing yet, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Store the generated images as file on hd. Limit the different widths and heights which are available so ppl don't fill your harddrive. Clean up old generated files with a cli cron script.

Comment: @OIS This is the most optimal solution possible, and I'll do that in the future. But for now, I want to know which of the above is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all cases, it is better to generate thumbnail images on upload and store them on disk as ready-to-serve images. Disk space is cheaper than computation power (and memory).

In the alternative option, you gotta run that resize script for each thumbnail, and each time it is processing a 10+million pixel image. Multiply that by the number of thumbnails you are showing, then multiply that by the number of visits.

Assuming your API cannot change, i.e. thumbnails and images are accessed via `<img src="image.php?n=image&w=300&h=400" alt="test" />`, your `image.php` could look something like this:

```
// generate file name according to dimensions
if ($_GET['w'] == '300' && $_GET['h'] == '400') {
    $filename = $_GET['n'] . '-thumbnail.jpg';
}
else if ($_GET['w'] == '600' && $_GET['h'] == '800') {
    $filename = $_GET['n'] . '-midsize.jpg';
}
else {
    $filename = $_GET['n'] . '-fullsize.jpg';
}

// Serve image 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('/path/to/imgs/'.$filename);
```

Obviously, you should include security checks/filters. The code can also be easily enhanced to support other types like `image/png` and `image/svg` etc.

Comment: As I said, save the generated resized image on disk. Then add cleanup which deletes it after a few days without being read. Add a folder for each possible width and height you want, and only allow files to be generated to those dimensions. It's easy really.